# Is there a D2L server-side setting for allowing access through API

Tags: c#, api, permissions, desire2learn, server-configuration

When I run the "Getting Started" C# project of DESIRE2LEARN, I always get

> The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

I don't provide values for UserId and UserKey fields for "Get Version" method, I only set Host, AppId, AppKey values for the **new server**, but it is not working still.

Then, I thought this could be related to wrong port#. I set it 443, but do not know what it is exactly. I set the port# wrong for D2L **test-server** in the working project file, and I got a different error:

> "Unable to connect to the remote server".

So, I do not think it is about port#. My guess is that this is about API-related permission issue in the server. Do you think that the administrator need to change the settings in the server accordingly, so that access through API could be possible? Have you ever needed to configure the server for allowing access through API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're retrieving a 403 (No Permission) error, it seems unlikely that your LMS has all support for the Valence Extensibility turned off (as it's likely that the API service layer itself is returning this error). It could be possible that the AppID/AppKey credentials that you're using are not recognized by your LMS. I suggest you [open an issue with the Valence issue tracker](https://d2l.fogbugz.com/default.asp?pg=pgPublicEdit), and work through the issue there. They may want your LMS admins to open a customer support ticket with Desire2Learn, in order to investigate the configuration of your LMS to ensure everything is properly set up.